# WPF Fixed Folder Directory

Tags: c#, wpf

I could open the Images folder which is in the Debug folder with these codes in Winform. How can i do that with WPF? Thank you

`openFile.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"Images");`

Comment: There is an [Open File Dialog](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-openfiledialog/) available in WPF as well.

Comment: Yes, i know that. I use it also. But how can i fix a folder when i use Open File Dialog. It opens myDocuments and i want that Images folder be the default folder. Thanx anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `Path.Combine`. You just need a different way of getting the executable path. This can be done with reflection.

```
var executablePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
openFile.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(executablePath, @"Images");
```

Comment: This gives error; But i solved the problem. Here is the codes:  var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var newPath=System.IO.Path.Combine(path, @"Images");
            openFile.InitialDirectory = newPath;

Comment: @AttilaAlan That's exactly what the OP said but you're extracting the folder name.